# Display problem in IE8

Tags: html, css

The following page is mucked up in IE8 -- the bulk of the content starts appearing half way down the screen and the tables/divs do not look as they should.  It works in other browsers and in IE8 compatibility mode.  I've inspected the HTML and can't work out what's wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

http://www.moviemonitor.com/browse/itunes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest removing the `min-height: 800px;` CSS value from the first DIV element after `<div id="mainContent">`. Apparently IE8 renders the first child block level element with that height irrespective of any other contained elements.

Then again, those HTML validation results are pretty grim. Try to fix some of the invalid HTML and make sure that all of your tags are closed properly.

Comment: I've removed that min-height value, and I've managed to improve the validation results -- down to 4 errors, 2 warnings, but it is still not displaying as intended.  Again, this seems to only be happening in IE8.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have further superfluous height attributes and that your use the IE8 Developer Tools (F12) to diagnose the problem. I can't readily modify your HTML using this tools, only some of he attributes. For example in the validation errors, you have Javascript code being interpreted as XHTML. Make sure you use XHTML comments (<!--- ... -->) around your Javascript blocks to prevent these errors. Add alt tags to your imgs. And place the title tag within the head tag. That should improve the validation a great deal.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It turns out the problem was with nested form tags.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick glance in Firefox and IE8, I'd say there is some malformed HTML in there somewhere.  Looks to me like a mismatched open/close tag that IE8 isn't forgiving.  Run the whole thing through an HTML validator.

Comment: Here's what the W3C validator has to say: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.moviemonitor.com%2Fbrowse%2Fitunes&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0